# Why do fonts look thinner in adobe and different and richer in sumatra pdf

Tags: fonts, pdf, viewers, adobe, sumatrapdf

[Same question posted on other portal :](https://superuser.com/questions/741672/font-looks-thinner-in-adobe-acrobat-reader?noredirect=1#comment954421_741672)

Why do fonts look thinner in adobe and different and richer in sumatra pdf.

**Sumatra**
[image: Sumatra PDF]

**Adobe**
[image: Adobe PDF]

**Adobe reader settings:**

[image]

Comment: There are known issues displaying certain fonts in Adobe Reader on GNU/Linux. I don't know whether these would affect Windows or not, though. (I thought Windows used entirely different technology to render fonts but perhaps I'm mistaken about that.)

Comment: i've learned to trust nothing but the image on paper, if the final output is destined for paper.

Comment: @barbarabeeton   Since this is a CV/Resume. They use certain scanning and filter process to find keywords from resumes. So the PDF stands a greater chance.

Comment: Sorry, this is clearly a viewer issue not a TeX one.